Encourage rephrasing questions to cure appearance of being opinion-based
Often times, new contributors to SO will phrase questions like "What is the best way to do XYZ". These questions often get closed for being 'primarily opinion-based', despite the question actually being primarily objective and the only change needed to cure the appearance of the question being "opinion-based" could be as simple as changing the title to "How do I do XYZ". SO of course allows voting on answers, so the seeking the "best" answer to a problem is clearly an inherent property the platform elicits and, in most cases, is not really a problematic aspect of the question. It just need not be stated in the question.
The site does already tell users asking question to avoid asking opinion-based questions, but I would propose this change that may greatly improve the experience for these new contributors:

In the closing reason description for closing questions as opinion-based, ask contributors to consider whether the question is truly opinion based and that answers simply asking for the "best" should be edited rather than closed

There may also be room for the community bot to help address things like this and maybe can be more deeply integrated into the new staging grounds. Some potential obstacles may include false positives, for example "finding best fit line in a data plot" where 'best fit' is a mathematical term, not one soliciting opinions.
I feel this will help a great deal to ensuring a better experience for users of the site, especially new contributors.
Related: Rename "Primarily Opinion Based"
One primary motivator I have here is that I've noticed a group of users on Stack Overflow who seem to programmatically identify questions using such language and immediately vote to close them even though they are, really, not primarily opinion-based when the only subjective/opinion-based element to the question is simply asking for the "best" solution to their problem. Despite this, the votes to close are usually successful, which is obviously a poor experience, especially for new contributors.

Such a warning already exists. "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed"

@KevinB Hmm. Interesting. I didn't see that. I did test and try to write a question like this, but didn't notice any warning. Does it only come up when you actually try to submit it?

It comes up during the review phase on the new(er) ask wizard

If that is the actual full warning... yeah it is a typical Stack Overflow one, inconsistent and incomplete. It should read "The question you're asking appears to be subjective/asking for opinions; it is likely to receive downvotes and be closed".

Besides that, I wouldn't think it would inspire much attention at this point in a person's (total lack of) understanding of the site. They likely don't even really know what it means for a question to be closed, or what repercussions it can have down the line. It's all just part of the annoyance generator.

It would be more actionable if it said which phrases triggered the warning or at least linked to something with detailed information about what it was checking for.
